# Selecting only one point in polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, point-in-polygon, select-by-location

I have two shapefiles: polygon(buffer) and point.

How can I select only one point in each buffer in QGIS?

If I use the "Select by Location", I will get all points inside the polygons, however I need only one? It doesn't matter which point out of two or more in polygon is selected.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `select by expression` with geometry intersection?

Comment: No, haven't tried that, not really sure how to write the expression.

Comment: I would have spatial join the points with the polygons, delete duplicates of the result, and then select the point by location with the deleted duplicates points. ```select by expression``` should be more efficient but you need those magical spell codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't care which point is selected, you can use this small PyQGIS script. Paste into a blank editor in the [Python Console](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html), change the layer names in the first two lines to match your layer names and click run.

```py
# Change layer names in the first two lines to match your layers...
point_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('New scratch layer')[0]
poly_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Buffered')[0]

ids = []

for feat in poly_lyr.getFeatures():
    contained_point = [f for f in point_lyr.getFeatures() if f.geometry().within(feat.geometry())][0]
    ids.append(contained_point.id())

point_lyr.selectByIds(ids)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works so perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

With the ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression%22) tool you can use:

```
array_first(
    array_agg(
        $id,
        group_by:=overlay_intersects('polygons', $id), -- replace 'polygons'
        filter:=array_length(overlay_intersects('polygons', $id)) > 0 -- replace 'polygons'
        )
    ) = $id
```

on your point layer. Replace the name of the `'polygons'` layer with the actual name and run it.

QGIS 3.16+ is required.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it would be:

- First do a ["Join Attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) (`Vector -> Data Management Tools`) with your points as the *Base Layer*, your polygons as the *Join
  Layer*, *"within"* as the Geometric predicate and for the *Join type* :
  "Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)".
  Remember you need to have [a Spatial index](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#create-spatial-index) for both your layers before doing
  this (`Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Create Spatial Index`)
- Then, now that all your points within the same polygon have the same attribute, use the ["Delete Duplicates by attribute"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicates-by-attribute) from the Processing toolbox in order to keep only one point inside each polygon.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

To add some performance improvements to [@Ben W's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431894/107424) by using a [`spatial index`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#create-spatial-index) and a [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) command:

```py
point_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')[0]
poly_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygons')[0]

ids = []
point_lyr.removeSelection() #clear selection

point_lyr_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(point_lyr.getFeatures()) # build a spatial index on the points

for polygon in poly_lyr.getFeatures():
    for pointid in point_lyr_idx.intersects(polygon.geometry().boundingBox()): # iterate only over points inside bbox of polygon
        point = point_lyr.getFeature(pointid)
        if point.geometry().within(polygon.geometry()): # check if point is actually inside polygon
            ids.append(point.id())
            break # stop iteration after first match and go to next polygon

point_lyr.selectByIds(ids)
```

Answer (score 3):

To add even more performance improvements to [@MrXsquared's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431910/144074) by using [`QgsGeometryEngine`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometryEngine.html) and skipping feature fetching:

```py
point_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')[0]
poly_lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygons')[0]

ids = []
point_lyr.removeSelection() #clear selection

# build a spatial index on the points (with flag to be able to retrieve geometries)
point_lyr_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(point_lyr.getFeatures(), flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries) 

for polygon in poly_lyr.getFeatures():
    poly_geometry_engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(polygon.geometry().constGet())
    poly_geometry_engine.prepareGeometry()

    for pointid in point_lyr_idx.intersects(polygon.geometry().boundingBox()): 
        # iterate only over points inside bbox of polygon
        point_geometry = point_lyr_idx.geometry(pointid)

        if poly_geometry_engine.contains(point_geometry.constGet()): # check if point is actually inside polygon
            ids.append(pointid)
            break # stop iteration after first match and go to next polygon

point_lyr.selectByIds(ids)
```

`QgsGeometryEngine` can be **really** powerful in some cases so it is useful to know about it (in some cases I have gotten a x100 performance improvement using it).

With these improvements you can get a ~20-30% improvement compared to [@MrXsquared's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431910/144074).

Comment: Neat thing! Would be interested in reading up about it more, do you have some references?

Comment: The detailed description of the class in the api documentation is the best/only reference i have found. I found it accidentally while reading the qgsgeometry documentation there doesn't seem to be a lot of documented use of this class which is a shame in my opinion considering the huge benefits it can provide for really intensive spatial operations

Comment: Especially because apparently this class has existed since qgis version 2.10

Comment: even in this article https://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/ written by one of the contributors of QGIS on the topic of optimizing pyqgis scripts it isn't mentioned at all

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a script, there is a built-in [Random selection within subsets](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#random-selection-within-subsets) tool. Before start you need to join by location `ID` of the polygons to your point data and specify that field in the `ID field` parameter.

[image]