# Selecting the maximum value from series of polygons that intersect with line in QGIS

Tags: polygon, line, overlapping-features, select-by-location, maximum

Is there a way to select the cell (single) with the maximum value in a polygon layer using the intersection of a line? The first image is the grid (polygon) layer with the attribute field `"VALUE"` and a line.

In the second image, the line crosses over cells A, B, C, D and E.

Is there a way to use the line to select the highest `"VALUE"` from A through E? In some cases, the line could be shorter or longer, so an expression that only took the line and the cells it crosses would be the best scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ["Select By Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with the following expression (replace 'Line' with the name of your line layer):

```
array_first(
    array_reverse(
        array_agg(
            $id,
            group_by:=overlay_intersects('Line', $id),
            filter:=array_length(overlay_intersects('Line', $id)) > 0,
            order_by:="VALUE"
            )
        )
    ) = $id
```

There are quite a few QGIS expression wizards on here (I'm not one of them but I'm trying to learn) so maybe someone will offer a better expression, but I have tested this and it works well.

[image]

Reference: I adapted the expression from MrXsquared [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431885/selecting-only-one-point-in-polygon-using-qgis/431911#431911).

Comment: I thought you will publish a PyQGIS solutions ^_^

Comment: Hello @Taras! I took the opportunity to try a different solution. I'm trying to improve my knowledge of expressions. As much as I use PyQGIS, sometimes I really appreciate the beauty and power of QGIS expressions (and admire the mastery that you and others have of them).

Comment: You did it great! As well as other things, especially the PyQGIS.

Comment: @Taras, thanks for the kind words :-)

Comment: I had no idea that so much could be done through QGIS expressions - thanks for sharing! Much more concise than writing it in pyQGIS.

Comment: It works! Thank you, Ben

Comment: @Anthony, great! Glad it worked.

Comment: @ScriptedChicken, thanks- no worries. I mostly use PyQGIS as well, but trying to learn more about expressions- they can really be magical!

Comment: @BenW is there a way to reference your expression in a batch process? If I had a Line folder and a Grid folder.

Comment: @BenW Thank you for your response :) Since the expression you provided requires a specific 'INPUT' which is the name of the line vector and it compares it to a Grid - was wondering how a folder Input 01 (containing all line vectors) could run your expression against a folder Input 02 containing all the grids. The line to grid is 1:1
If there are 500 line layers in Input 01 there are 500 grid (polygon) layers in Input 2. The batch processing option does not have a column for the grid input. Does this make sense? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hi @Anthony. Yes, TBH I'm not sure how you would feed inputs from 2 folders into a batch process with an expression. If you want pursue that approach, I would suggest asking a new question. I'm sure I could write a pyqgis script to do it, but some questions are: how would you match the correct line and grid files to each other? By some naming convention, or would they need to be linked spatially e.g by checking if their extents intersect?

Comment: Also, if you are iterating over 2 input folders (and 500 is quite a few files), I take it the files are not loaded as layers in QGIS. In that case, what kind of result/ output would you like? Select features in each grid and load them in at the end? Extract the maximum grid feature for each line and create an output layer for each grid file? Or add all maximum grid features to a single output layer? Cheers.

Comment: @Anthony, here is a link to a Python script I have written which you can try in the QGIS Python console. There are notes and instructions at the start of the script. The output will be a polygon memory layer containing all the maximum grid cells for intersecting lines for all layers in two input directories. Let me know how you go. https://gist.github.com/benwirf/ccb3b0beb25f1bcd35fba81d8ddb10f1

Answer (score 2):

The can be done through pyQGIS. The script below will need to be updated with your layer names, but the bones of the functionality in there. Hope this helps

```
lines = QgsProject.instance().getLayersByName("Lines Layer")[0]
poly = QgsProject.instance().getLayersByName("Polygons Layer")[0]

# get all fids for lines features
fids = []
for lineFtr in lines.getFeatures():
    fids.append(ftr.id())

# begin edit session
with edit(lines):
    for fid in fids:
        # set filter to only use one line feature each time
        lines.setSubString(f"$id = {fid}")

        # create virtual layer of all overlapping polys
        res = processing.run("native:extractbylocation", {
            'INPUT': poly,\
            'PREDICATE': [0],\ # 0 = extracting only intersecting polys
            'INTERSECT': line,\
            'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
        })
        output = res["OUTPUT"]

        # get max value from overlapping polys
        polyValues = []
        for ftr in output.getFeatures():
            value = ftr["VALUE"]
            polyValues.append(value)
        maxValue = max(polyValues)

        # save max value in current line feature
        for lineFtr in lines.getFeatures():
            lineFtr["MAX_VALUE"] = maxValue
        
        # update line feature
        lines.updateFeature(lineFtr)
        
print("Completed")
```

Comment: The script produced a few errors in my Python Console - thank you for taking the time to answer my question